# Get Corrupt data from server while upload image

Tags: ios, json, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I get success in  converting image to base64 string but when i serve to server, server get corrupt data 
I am using  http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter# for  get proper output of image

```
 NSString *base64String=[UIImagePNGRepresentation(ProfileImageView.image)
    base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];
 [base64String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n\r" withString:@""];
 [base64String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];  


   NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&UserName=%@&Password=%@&Email=%@&MobileNo=%@&Profiledata=%@",[_DicData valueForKey:@"userId"],[_DicData valueForKey:@"userName"],[_DicData valueForKey:@"password"] ,[_DicData valueForKey:@"email"],MobileNumberLable.text,base64String];

    NSString *strurl2=@"api/UpdateUserProfledata/";
    NSString *strurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_Url1,strurl2];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strurl];
    NSData *postData= [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

    NSString *authtoken=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ios %@",[_DicData valueForKey:@"authToken"]];
    [req setValue:authtoken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *err = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&err];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

When i convert image from my side i get 
Total Character =133624 And Total Word=0 
But when server convert it get
Total Character =133624 And Total Word=2891
Help Me!

Backend code for image converter in .net

public UserViewModel UpdateUserProfiledata(UserViewModel userupdate)
        {
            UserViewModel model = new UserViewModel();
            if (userupdate != null && userupdate.UserId > 0)
            {
                var getuser = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetMany(x => x.UserId == userupdate.UserId).ToList();
                if (getuser.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in getuser)
                    {
                        item.UserName = userupdate.UserName;
                        item.Email = userupdate.Email;
                        item.MobileNo = userupdate.MobileNo;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userupdate.Profiledata))
                        {
                            var img = GetBytes(userupdate.Profiledata);
                            item.ProfilePhoto = img;
                        }
                        model.Profiledata = userupdate.Profiledata.Trim();
                        _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Update(item);
                        _unitOfWork.Save();
                        return model;
                    }
                }
            }
            return model;
        }
        static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *dataImage=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1);
NSString *base64String = [self base64forData:dataImage];
```

Pass this `base64String` to server in your request.

Try this for base64 encoding:

```
- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData
{
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;
}
```

Comment: what is this        static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="; ?  @Bhadresh Mulsaniya

Comment: It's for converting your image data character to binary format buy AND operation with 0x3F.

Comment: Have you try this Category https://github.com/yllan/FoundationAddition ?

Comment: thanks brother but i cant get any idea from your  Category

Comment: Have you try with anyone?

Comment: No  @Bhadresh Mulsaniya

Comment: when i call this method what i pass as a NSData parameter? @Bhadresh

Comment: Convert your image into NSData and call this function, it will return you string which you can send it to server.

Comment: if i convert image to NSData i get ByteArray data not base 64String and server accept only base64 String brother @Bhadresh

Comment: Have you convert it with above function?

Comment: with above function??? NOO i convert with following method NSData *ImgData=[UIImagePNGRepresentation(ProfileImageView.image)base64EncodedDataWithO‌​ptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength]; [UserProfileViewController base64forData:ImgData];   @Bhadresh

Comment: Then try with above function. Pass NSData like this [self base64Data:[UIImagePNGRepresentation(ProfileImageView.image);]

Comment: Still i get corrupt data brother :(:( @ Bhadresh Mulsaniya

Comment: Which technology you are using at backend?

Comment: At server side you are using php, java, .net ?

Comment: Aacha! i am using .NET

Comment: With the help of your code i get data in binary array but my server accept only Base64 String. I converted binary array to base64 but not getting success

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check you have done like that or different way.

Comment: I tried it but still get corrupt data bro. Actully what's the function of above funtion that you suggested?  @Bhadresh Mulsaniya

Comment: - (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData
{
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

 }

Comment: Which is in my answer.

Comment: please add me to personal chat bro @Bhadresh Mulsaniya

Comment: i asked what is aim of < - (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData > this function brother @Bhadresh Mulsaniya

Comment: Convert your image into base64 string.

Comment: NSData *img=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ProfileImageView.image, 1);
    [UserProfileViewController base64forData:img];     This is the way i calling base64forData funtion but i get ByteArray not base64string @ Bhadresh Mulsaniya

Comment: Try with this : http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html